# Higher homotopy groups and ramified covering maps

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds

It  is  known  in  elementary  algebraic  topology that a  covering  map  induces  an isomorphism  of  higher  homotopy  groups.

Is  there  any  relation  of  the  higher  homotopy  groups  of  the  total  space  of  a ramified  covering in the  sense  of  topology (a map which  is  a  covering  map  outside  of  a  nowhwere dense  set) and  its  base space? I  am  interested  in  base  spaces  which  are   manifolds  with mild singularities.

Comment: Probably there is nothing at all one can say. Think of the torus, a ramified cover of the 2-sphere.